# why doesn't scons Package copy h files?

Tags: python, package, scons

I have a project with many subdirectories and types of files (python, c++, configuration files, images, etc).
When I use SCons env.Package like this:

```
    env.Package( 
    NAME           = 'isid',
    VERSION        = '1.0', 
    PACKAGEVERSION = '11',
    PACKAGETYPE    = 'rpm',
    LICENSE        = 'gpl',
    SUMMARY        = 'just a test',
    DESCRIPTION    = 'the most test app in the world',
    X_RPM_GROUP    = 'Application/isid',
    SOURCE_URL     = 'http://isid.com/versions/isid-1.0.11.tar.gz',
)
```

I get **everything** in isid-1.0.11.tar.gz *except* for the h files. 
This automatically leads to build errors in ./isid-1.0.11 that stops rpmbuild from running.

**EDIT**

My project is split into few subdirectories.
In each I have SConscript that starts with these lines, or similar, depending on the includes it needs:

```
  # import all variables
  Import('*') 

  include = Dir([ 
     '../inc/',
  ])

  local_env = env.Clone( CPPPATH = include )
```

SConstruct just defines the variables and calls SConscript() on each subdirectory.

The call to Package is done in SConstruct, so I guess SCons indeed does not know the dependencies.

snippet of 
`# scons --tree=prune:`

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-correlator
  | +-correlator/SConscript
  | +-correlator/collector
  | +-correlator/correlation_command
  | | +-correlator/correlation_command/app_command_device.cpp
  | | +-correlator/correlation_command/app_command_device.h
  | | +-correlator/correlation_command/app_command_device.o
  | | | +-correlator/correlation_command/app_command_device.cpp
  | | | +-correlator/correlation_command/app_command_device.h
  | | | +-correlator/entity/entity.h
  | | | +-infra/inc/app_command/app_command.h
  | | | +-/bin/g++
  | | +-correlator/correlation_command/app_command_event.cpp
  | | +-correlator/correlation_command/app_command_event.h
```

**EDIT #2**

Here is a complete, minimal, example that produces the same problem.
To reproduce the problem, run:

> scons pack=1.0 ver=1

files:
SConstruct.
app1/SConscript
app1/main.cpp
app1/inc.h

**Listing**

SConstruct

```
 1  
 2  # main file
 3  
 4  env = Environment(tools=['default', 'packaging'])
 5  
 6  Export( 'env' )
 7  
 8  flags = [ 
 9      '-Wall',
10      '-Werror',
11      '-g',
12      '-ggdb3',
13      '-gdwarf-2',
14      '-std=c++11',
15  ]
16  
17  env.Append( CPPFLAGS = flags ) 
18  
19  
20  scripts = []
21  
22  Sapp1 = 'app1/SConscript'
23  scripts.append( Sapp1 )
24  
25  
26  env.SConscript( scripts )
27  
28  pack = ARGUMENTS.get('pack', '')
29  ver = ARGUMENTS.get('ver', '99' )
30  if pack:
31      env.Package( 
32          NAME           = 'app1',
33          VERSION        = pack,
34          PACKAGEVERSION = ver,
35          PACKAGETYPE    = 'rpm',
36          LICENSE        = 'private',
37          SUMMARY        = 'exampe app #1',
38          DESCRIPTION    = 'the most powerfull exampe #1',
39          X_RPM_GROUP    = 'Application/app1',
40          SOURCE_URL     = 'http://example.com/1/app1-1.0.1.tar.gz',
41      )
42
```

app1/SConscript

```
 1  
 2  # import all variables
 3  Import('*')
 4  
 5  # add specific include directory
 6  
 7  include = Dir( [
 8      '.',
 9  ])
10  
11  local_env = env.Clone( CPPPATH = include )
12  
13  # define sources
14  sources = [ 
15      'main.cpp',
16  ]
17  
18  libs = [
19  ]
20  
21  main_name = 'app1',
22  
23  main_obj = local_env.Program( target = main_name, source = sources, LIBS = libs )
24  
25  # install
26  install_dir = '/opt/rf/app1'
27  install_files = [ main_obj ] 
28  
29  local_env.Install( dir = install_dir, source = install_files )
30  local_env.Command( install_dir, install_files, "chown -R rf:rfids $TARGET" )
31  
32  
33  local_env.Alias( 'install', install_dir )
```

app1/main.cpp

```
     1  
 2  #include "inc.h"
 3  
 4  
 5  int main()
 6  {
 7      int l = g;
 8  
 9      return l;
10  }
```

app1/inc.h

```
 1  
 2  int g = 100;
```

output:

```
# scons pack=1.0 ver=1
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o app1/main.o -c -Wall -Werror -g -ggdb3 -gdwarf-2 -std=c++11 -Iapp1 app1/main.cpp
g++ -o app1/app1 app1/main.o
LC_ALL=C rpmbuild -ta /home/ran/work/rpmexample/app1-1.0.1.tar.gz
scons: *** [app1-1.0-1.src.rpm] app1-1.0-1.src.rpm: Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.wU9lDZ
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILD
+ '[' -n /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64 -a /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64
+ cd /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILD
+ rm -rf app1-1.0
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/ran/work/rpmexample/app1-1.0.1.tar.gz
+ /usr/bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd app1-1.0
+ /usr/bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.gVaX4j
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILD
+ cd app1-1.0
+ '[' '!' -e /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64 -a /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ mkdir /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.JWAdxE
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILD
+ '[' /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64
++ dirname /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64
+ cd app1-1.0
+ scons --install-sandbox=/home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64 /home/ran/work/rpmexample/rpmtemp/BUILDROOT/app1-1.0-1.x86_64
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o app1/main.o -c -Wall -Werror -g -ggdb3 -gdwarf-2 -std=c++11 -Iapp1 app1/main.cpp
app1/main.cpp:2:17: fatal error: inc.h: No such file or directory
 #include "inc.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [app1/main.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.JWAdxE (%install)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.JWAdxE (%install)

scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Can you give some more info about how your project is set up in general? Especially concerning the automatic detection of implicit dependencies? My inital guess is, that you didn't specify the CPPPATH variable correctly, or aren't using it at all, such that SCons is unable to detect that a C/CPP file "foo.c" depends on its header "foo.h".

Comment: I added more information in the question body.

Comment: I have set CPPPATH just before calling Package() - done no good. I tried packaging just one library, where I definitely have CPPPATH declared correctly - done no  good either. Looking for more options.

Comment: Look at the output from scons --tree=prune It should give you some indication of which files SCons "knows" about and which the package depends on.  Can you include a complete minimal SConstruct/SConscript to reproduce the issue? That would help.

Comment: snippet of scons --tree=prune, was added to the question

Comment: added minimal example to the question.